# HTTP POST Requests not working

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, php-7.1

I am having trouble on my Ubuntu (17.10) LAMP installation (php 7.1). I am assuming it is misconfigured but have been unable to find in document or google how to fix it. Post requests work fine going to a same page, but posts requests to another page do not work. Note, both of these pages are on the same server.

Referencing the following file, if I enter data (123, and ABC) and click the "Submit Local", I get:

[image]

If I enter data (567, and AAA) and click the "Submit Remote", I get:

[image]

testPost.php:

```
  echo "testPost.php<BR/>\n" ;

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $key;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
?>
</table>


<form action="" method="POST">
<input name="PostData1" type="text" />
<input name="PostData2" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit self" value="Submit Local">
</form>


<form action="http://www.swsuperman.com/PostTest.php" method="POST">
<input name="PostData1" type="text" />
<input name="PostData2" type="text" />
<input type="submit" name="submit remote" value="Submit Remote">
</form>
```

PostTest.php :

```
<table>
<?php 
  echo "PostTest.php<BR/>\n" ;


    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $key;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td>";
        echo $value;
        echo "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }


?>
</table>
```

Comment: I checked your website and remote post doesn't work because you use some iframe logic after post request, there's another get request.

Comment: Thanks Kamil, but I do not understand your comment, what do you mean by iframe logic ? The code I am using is as shown in the post ?

Comment: Please analyze this
http://take.ms/zL6ji
http://take.ms/M9VuU
http://take.ms/cH3Y5

Comment: you should change remote address to http://108.53.128.29/PostTest.php

Comment: @Kamil. Thanks ! Now I am really confused, any idea why the hardcoded IP works but not the URL ?

Comment: As @KamilKarkus said before, you are having a GET after the POST request, when making a POST straight to the IP address, it will work, because there are no GET from any Name server to resolve the IP and give the response, I mean, when you are making a request directly to IP you have something like "client" -> "server", but when you make to the name, you will have something like "client" -> "name server" -> "server", got it?